# SSH to a machine that is getting it's network connection from an Android device(Google TV)

Tags: linux, ssh, ip, routing, android

I have a Linux(Ubuntu) machine for my HTPC. It's running XBMC and I control it via my IR remote control. I don't have a (wired) keyboard to control it. It has Wifi adaptor but it's not installed. I also have a Sony Google TV (model [NSZ-GT1](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/2442014824590953531?es_sm=91&sclient=psy-ab&q=sony%20google%20tv%20blue%20ray&oq=sony%20google%20tv%20blue%20ray&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.53899372,d.cGE,pv.xjs.s.en_US.E_HR746bqA4.O&espv=210&biw=1342&bih=806&dpr=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=gc9ZUpTLJMj5igKvuoDICA.1381617538567.5&ei=kM9ZUsjwLYPUiwKFnoH4BQ&ved=0CJIEEKYrMAA)) which runs Android 3.0 and have Wifi and an ethernet port. Luckily I was able to connect a wire from Google TV to XBMC machine and get internet connection. My wireless modem is far away and I don't have a long cable to connect XBMC machine directly to it.

With all weird setup I have, now I want to SSH to the XBMC to try to install Wifi adapter on it. XBMC show IP address and MAC address of machine. SSH-ing to IP times out.

Can I use MAC address for SSH to bypass Google TV? Is there anything smart in software side that I can do to avoid a lot of physical work?

Comment: You can't give a MAC address to ssh. Even if you could, it would be pointless because a MAC address is only meaningful on a network segment, but here you need an address that's routed by the Google TV. [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) is where routing happens. Does the Google TV have a [tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) setting? If so, use it.

Comment: Spending a couple of bucks on a USB keyboard seems like the easiest and fastest way. Provided your HTPC has USB, of course.